# Heroku rails app crash on first http request but then works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, crash

This is really annoying. It works fine locally (development) but when I push it to Heroku it crashes on the first HTTP request, then if I press F5 it works fine. So it seems to crash when the app first spins up. ANY advise would be greatly appreciated!

I think this is where the error is in the Heroku Log output:

2012-04-14T20:09:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Sass::SyntaxError (File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon.

...

2012-04-14T19:08:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'

Complete Heroku Log Output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rvdkPwzR